# Overlay does not move when hovering over a promoted link tile

Tags: promoted-links, overlay, tiles

something in the settings for promoted links prevents the overlay from popping up when I point my mouse on it .. and I cannot figure what it could be. Would you have any ideas and be able to help me fixing it?

My tiles are set as multiline promoted link using a js script.

Comment: check console for script errors

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using javascript to split the tiles into multiple rows, you can achieve this using CSS and don't have to risk to "break" any other element with the script.

From an old answer of mine:

"Instead of using jQuery, you could try a CSS-only solution, tinkering with nothing more than the width. Might give you better control over the promoted links.

```
<style>
/*display rows of 3 items*/
.ms-promlink-body {
      width: 480px;
}
```

Easy way to display promoted links (tiles) on multiple rows

If you need to target a specific promoted links list, you can do it with the web parts ID.

```
<style type="text/css">
#WebPartWPQX .ms-promlink-body {
      width: 480px;
}
```

In the class **#WebPartWPQX**, X should be a number which you can find by using F12 developer tools ( Press F12 in the browser ) and click on the list to find the web part ID. So it should be WebPartWPQ1 as a example."

To change the font for the tiles, just add this CSS

```
.ms-promlink-body {
    font-family: Verdana;
}
```

[Formatting the layout of multiple promoted links](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144853/formatting-the-layout-of-multiple-promoted-links/144857#144857)

Comment: Thanks, Christoffer. I removed JS code, and followed your way now. It works! Now I wonder how to add more text into the description of each promoted link, so it would contain not just Title, but also few lines explaining the content of each.

Comment: Corrected comment. Thanks, @Christoffer. I removed JS code, and followed your way now. It works! Now I wonder how to edit the font of the title & description of each promoted link.

Comment: To add description, you edit the promoted links description fields (shows when you hover the tile)

Comment: See my updates answer for changing the font.